# Hide field when parent.level is lower then 5?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-mptt

How can i hide a field "content", when parent level is lower then 5 in mptt.django ? I want edit a field when descendent is 5.

```
class Menu(MPTTModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
content = models.TextField(verbose_name='content')
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if parent and parent.level <= 5:
        self.exclude = ("content", )
```

i want create somethink of that

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, would you please tell more details about your problem?

Comment: I dont know, how to hide a a field "content" in panel admin, before i create for example 5 descendents in admin. I need to be able edit "content" only on 5 lvl tree or higher.

Comment: try use edit to post your code so everyone can read it easily.

Comment: i have hope you can undarstant what i mean